# ios accessing app level properties easily

Tags: ios

I have a property in `AppDelegate` that I would like to grab easily. So far it's not working for me as planned:

`[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] wasLoggedIn] = YES`

## AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wasLoggedIn;
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    wasLoggedIn = false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] wasLoggedIn] = YES;
```

Should be

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] wasLoggedIn] = YES;
```

You're calling the method on the UIApplication instance at the moment.